# Control ID generated by DITA_OT transform of imageMap to HTML

Tags: dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I have a DITA topic that includes an `imagemap`.

When published to HTML (responsive webhelp) two HTML components are generated, an `img` and a `map`.  These must be connected via an `id` field, for which DITA_OT freshly generates a unique one each time.

This triggers unnecessary changes in our version control system.

Is there a way of specifying the ID value to be used to link the two HTML components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique IDs are generated in the XSLT stylesheet "DITA-OT/plugins/org.dita.html5/xsl/ut-d.xsl" in the template:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' ut-d/imagemap ')]" name="topic.ut-d.imagemap">
```

using the generate-id() function. From what I know and what I tested I assume that if the processed DITA content remains exactly the same, the generated IDs should not change. Can you perform a similar test? Publish the same DITA Map twice to two output folders, then check if this generated ID is different in the two folders.

But you could also try to take control over the IDs by creating a DITA OT plugin which overrides this entire xsl template and lets you take control over the ID value.

Comment: Hello +Radu the contents of the imagemap are unchanged, but a new ID is generated each time: https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/cpVId81kbopp.png

Comment: I think that I tested with plain HTML5 output and the ID remained the same between consecutive publishing tasks, can you test this on your side?
I think because the Webhelp output slightly changes the HTML content every time it publishes (by adding those build id timestamps for example) the id generation also changes in the imagemap. I will add an issue on our side with your use case. In the meantime as I said with an XSLT customization you can take control over the generated IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back, here's an alternative answer:

Deliverables produced by the publishing process (PDFs, EPUBs, HTML+CSS+JS files) should not be kept in a version control system as they are never manually edited by the end user.

The version control system should keep the input files (DITA XML, Markdown, etc) and the publishing system should use SSH to connect to a certain folder on the HTTP server and upload the final deliverables (PDF, HTML, etc) there.

Because we used to do this for our own web site, keep the XML files and the HTML files in the same version controlled project which ended up being bloated without any real benefit.

Comment: You are quite right Radu - only source data should be under Version control.  In this case, temporarily storing published HTML under Version Control is just a convenient way of providing a hosted version of document in GitHub Pages, to ease third-party review - and avoid domain experts having to know how to publish the document themselves.